# Slackのアカウントの概念を知りたい

Tags: slack

Slackは1つのメールアドレスで、複数のワークスペースにサインインする事が出来ます。
ワークスペースごとに別々のプロフィール(パスワード、プロフィール画像、表示名)が設定できます。

その上で、Slackで「(**ワークスペースではなく**)Slackサービスのアカウント」というのはどこで確認出来るのでしょうか？

最初は「SlackはワークスペースごとのアカウントでSlackサービス自体のアカウントは無いのかな」と思っていたのですが
↓このslackのappを作成し登録するページはどのアカウントという概念が無いみたいなので、「Slackサービス自体のアカウント」というものは存在すると思っています。
https://api.slack.com/apps/

インストールされたアプリの一覧ページ等はURLにワークスペースのIDが含まれているので、これはワークスペースごとに分離されているみたいですが、上記のapiのページはワークスペースごとの分離がありませんでした。
https://app.slack.com/apps-manage/XXXXXX/integrations/installed

---

以下のワークスペースごとの管理者確認画面で自分が「プライマリーオーナー」になっているワークスペースがSlackのアカウントになるのかと思ったのですが
プライマリーオーナーの権限は別の人に譲渡する事が出来ます
つまり、自分がプライマリーオーナーのワークスペースが0個の場合と、
自分がプライマリーオーナーのワークスペースが2個以上存在する場合があるが
その時Slackのアカウントはどういう扱いになるのか分からない
https://XXXXXX.slack.com/account/workspace-settings#admins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おっしゃるとおりSlack全体の共通アカウントというものはないんじゃないでしょうか。

https://app.slack.com/apps-manage/XXXXXX/integrations/installed

がどのページか分からないですが XXXXX はワークスペースを表してたりしませんか？